# Why do while loop doesn't work correctly?

Tags: c, loops, random, srand

I wrote some C code to generate a random character and check if this character exists in an array. If it exist, I want to re-generate a new char. I'm using a flag as an indicator and used a `do`/`while` loop to check this flag, but unfortunately the code doesn't work as desired and I get a character that already exist in the array.

I need your help to understand and solve this problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    int num;
    int flag = -1;
    char temp[5] = { '3', '2', '5', '9', '1' };
    srand(time(NULL));
    do {
        num = rand() % 5;
        c = num;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (temp[i] == c) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (0 == flag);

    printf("number is : %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `5` is a number. `'5'` is a character. The difference between the two is `'0'`. I.e. `'5' == 5 + '0'`

Comment: so , what should i do is to modify the condition in the for loop to be like that ```c if(temp[i] == c+'0' ) ``` or what ? :D 
i'll appreciate if you give me an example :)

Comment: ^ This is one of the solutions.

Comment: @Ahmedhamdy: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems:

- `5` and `'5'` are not the same thing. `'5'` is a character value whereas `5` is a numeric value. Character values depend on the character encoding, most likely ASCII on current systems, where `'5'` has a numeric value of `53` (`0x35`).
- the C Standard guarantees that the character digits `'0'` to `'9'` are contiguous, so you can draw a character digit by adding `'0'` to the random number.
- you should set `flag` to `1` before the `for` loop and only clear it when you find the character.
- note that you draw a character among `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. You might instead want all character digits included?

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char temp[] = { '3', '2', '5', '9', '1' };
    const size_t temp_len = sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0]);
    char c;
    int flag;

    srand(time(NULL));

    do {
        // select a random digit character 
        c = '0' + rand() % 10;
        flag = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < temp_len; i++) {
            if (temp[i] == c) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 0);

    printf("character is: %c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can use `memchr()` to search for the character and avoid using `do`/`while` loops that tend to cause confusion. Here is a simpler alternative:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char temp[] = { '3', '2', '5', '9', '1' };
    char c;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (;;) {
        // select a random digit character 
        c = '0' + rand() % 10;
        if (!memchr(temp, c, sizeof temp))
            break;
    }
    printf("character is: %c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion on the second solution: use `sizeof(temp)` instead of the constant `5`, especially since you recommend changing the size of `temp`. Asking the maintainer to figure out which constants in the program are supposed to be the size of `temp` or half the size of `temp`, and which mean something else, is just asking for bugs. Or even `sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0])`, if it’s possible the algorithm could be changed to use wide characters. If that’s too much to type, `#define NDIGITS (sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]))` or something.

Comment: Looks much better, although as a stylistic choice, I never write `for (;;)`.  I prefer `while (true)`.  In this case, I personally would have written `do {/*...*/} while (memchr(temp, c, sizeof temp));`.

Comment: @Davislor: Your alternative works fines, but I have strong feelings against `do`/`while`: this construct is very often misused by newbie programmers and sometimes savvy programmers alike. I don't ike `while (true)` either for 2 reasons: `true` is a recent addition to the standard, and `for (;;)` is an eye catcher.

Comment: @Davislor: since we are nitpicking, I would definitely prefer `countof(temp)` or `const size_t ndigits = sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0])` over `#define NDIGITS (sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]))`

Comment: I don’t think those alternatives are standard C11? But yes, in C++, I would definitely write a `constexpr` expression for `ndigits`. I typically use signed math and `ptrdiff_t` for my indices to avoid bugs like the notorious `3U < -1`.

Comment: And your code is fine; it comes down to personal coding style.

Comment: Thanks all your answers helped me  a lot :)

Comment: @Davislor: sadly `countof` is not a C Standard operator, it should be defined as 
a macro as `#define countof(a)  (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))` and applying it to a pointer will produce a confusing error that may go unnoticed. Regarding the `const` variable definition, it is perfectly correct C code and will be optimized out at compile time.

Comment: Standard C does let you use `ndigits`, declared that way, as a function argument. So, yes, it works fine here. I’m in the habit of using `#define` because some C compilers don’t treat a `const size_t` as an integer constant expression that you can use in array declarations. So I needed a `#define NDIGITS` to declare multiple arrays that are the same size. Or I could switch to C++.

Comment: @Davislor: of course using `ndigits` as the size of the array in not C89 conformant. `ndigits` is computed from the array size. The definition does not require an explicit size, the size is determined from the initializer.

Comment: Right, but I’m sure we’ve both run into situations where we needed a `#define` for an array size.  This is getting off-topic, though. Good answer, fine as it is.